# Why are my items returning twice and as empty elements?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am honestly not sure why this does not work. As previously stated it does not seem to be returning any of my predefined items. Would appreciate any help with this. Angular has been a pain lately and all the errors are quite new to me as I've jhust recently started. Thank you so much in advance

Here are my files, starting with the html:

```
---------------------------
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div *ngIf="students">
      <ul *ngFor="let student of students" class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <h3>{{ student.studentname }}</h3>
          <h3>{{ student.studentsurname }}</h3>
          <h3>{{ student.studentnumber }}</h3>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My regular ts

```
----------------------------------------------------
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentService } from '../student.service';
import { Student } from '../student.model';

import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentService } from '../student.service';
import { Student } from '../student.model';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-students',
  templateUrl: './all-students.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-students.component.css']
})
export class AllStudentsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{

  constructor(private studentService: StudentService) { }
  studentSub: Subscription;
  students: Student[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.students = this.studentService.getStudents();
    this.studentService.studentChanged.next(this.students)
    this.studentSub = this.studentService.studentChanged.subscribe(
      (students: Student[]) => {
        this.students = this.studentService.getStudents();
      }
    )
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){

  }
}
```

My injectable

```
---------------------------------------------------
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from './student.model';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentService {

  private students: Student[] = [
    new Student('Varughese', 'Mathew', 3459879),
    new Student('Sammy', 'Banamy', 3978462)
  ];

  studentChanged = new Subject<Student[]>()

  getStudent(index: number){
    return this.students[index];
  }

  getStudents(){
    return this.students.slice();
  }

  addStudent(student: Student){
    this.students.push(student);
    this.studentChanged.next(this.students.slice())
  }

  addStudents(students: Student[]){
    this.students.push(...students);
    this.studentChanged.next(this.students.slice())
  }
}
```

Again, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the names to match those of the student class.
If your class names are not the same it will not work

```
div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
<div *ngIf="students">
  <ul *ngFor="let student of students" class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <h3>{{ student.stname}}</h3>
      <h3>{{ student.stsurname }}</h3>
      <h3>{{ student.stnumber}}</h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, I had a hunch about that but I didn't end up tryiing it. Thank you so much

Comment: Your class names dont match your names in your string interpolation.

Comment: My string interpolation?

Comment: Yes it is the curly braces you use in your html {}